# Magento2 admin login asking for captcha even if password is correct

Tags: magento2

I have a strange problem currently with my Magento2 shop (version 2.4.3). When I login on my admin page, the logging is saying wrong captcha and wants to have a captcha input.
But the password was definetely correct.
If I than login again with the given captcha login is successful.
If I logout and login again, it is working wihtout the captcha.

This happens every day the first time when I try to login.

Any idea what this could be?

Regards,
Chequille